# Hibernate - oneToMany or only embedded

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I;'m starting with Hibernate. I have a simple question. 
I'm trying to do a application in JSF2 that app should imitates simple football statistics portal. There is couple of Entities: ... Club and Player. 
I want to do a relation beetween Club and Player:
Club:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "playersClub",
        orphanRemoval = true
)
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
@ContainedIn
private Set<Player> players;
```

and Player:

```
    @ManyToOne
//        (
//            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
//    )
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)
    private Club playersClub;
```

Here's my question, when i thought about this app there was an idea: when 1 club have for ex. 20 players and user's going to delete all of them the club should still be in app, but when user want delete club - then all of the players in this club should be deleted too( or user will see alert - there is xx players - do you want delete them desite . .)
Should I use ManyToOne/OneToMany or Embedded Player in Club?

Comment: I mean i can't select matching annotations to do when I user want to delete Club then all of the players should be deleted automaticly from DB.

Answer (score 0):

When you model you think of entities: *Player* is a "strong" entity (players can exist without clubs) and therefore you should use `ManyToOne/OneToMany` because that represents your model. And in your business logic you can decide weather you are going to delete players when you delete a club, or leave players club-less. Modeling this way also gives you the option to change the delete logic easily.

Comment: No, no. Rather club can exists without Players. in this situation my relations are ok?